# django iterate over a list that is an item of a queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a list that is generated by a method on one of my models. On the home page it works wonderfully, however when I go to a detail view of one project I can access all the parts of that project as they are direct fields of the Model, but I can't access the items in the list.

Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):

    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    others = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    closed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def updates(self):
        updates = []
        sequence_id = 1
        categories = set(self.update_set.all().values_list(
                         'category__id', flat=True))

        for cat_id in categories:
            a = Update.objects.filter(
                project=self, category__id=cat_id).order_by('added').last()
            if cat_id == sequence_id:
                updates.append(a)
            else:
                for i in range(cat_id - sequence_id):
                    updates.append('null')
                updates.append(a)
                sequence_id = cat_id
            sequence_id += 1
        return updates

class Update(models.Model):

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(UpdateCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    update = models.TextField(max_length=240, blank=True)
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.update
```

The view is simple:

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):

    template_name = 'project_portal/project_detail.html'
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
```

and here is the dynamic url that I am using:

```
path('project/<int:pk>/',
     ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
```

As for the template, I'm lost, here is one of the things I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "project_portal/base.html" %}
{% block home %}
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <div>
      <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      {% if object_list %}
      {% for item in updates %}

      <p>{{ item }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
      <h2>No records found for this project</h2>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What do I need to do to access the "updates" list that gets generated?

Comment: I thought a `DetailView` was supposed to view a single item.  Why do you need `.objects.all()`?

Comment: Also, do you perhaps mean to iterate through `object_list` and get individual `object`s and then call `object.updates` to access the property? I'm not sure why you are expecting `updates` to be in the namespace on its own, as it's still a property of a `Project`.

Comment: @JohmGordon no, a DetailView still has a queryset property which defines the queryset to find the individual item in. Admittedly, in this case that could be replaced by `model = Project`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` is a property of the model instance, you need to access it from there like any other attribute. Also note, there is no `object_list` in a detail view.

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  {% for item in object.updates %}
  <p>{{ item }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: So the issue I am having is that the update data is split into 7 categories. I need to be able to access those updates by project and then by category as well. The @property has made the update attribute a list of all the updates regardless of their category. I tried to put them into a dictionary that would use the category key as the key of the key/value pairs which worked nicely, but I have not been able to unpack that dictionary within the template correctly and all that I get back is a list of numbers, no numbers and an error saying that there was only one thing to unpack not two.

Comment: Well, show that code please. Most likely you need to iterate through `mydict.items`.

Comment: I've added the Update model for you, I can add more, but these are the only two models that I need to get data from, the other models are effectively static tables outlining priority of high, medium and low, and a table outlining the seven categories with a key. Let me know if you need anymore, the template is where I'm stuck, so that is all I have for this page until I can get it to work, as making it pretty is fine it's the functionality that is causing issues.

Comment: No, it was the dictionary stuff I wanted you to post.

Comment: Ok, on closer look at my project, I think I was hacking this a little too much and I was advised that a list was a better option. So I have written a second method on my project class that populates the second page and so is not relevant to this question. Your original post actually solved my issue for the moment, so marked it correct. Thank you for your input.